# How to set stored procedure variable in case statement

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck with a problem in SQL Server 2016. I wrote a stored procedure where I need a variable which is equal with the date of the first day of the actual year. However I need to set it in a case statement because I have to examine what value is has by the user. It's says

> 'Incorrect syntax near SET atm.

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Truck_Life] 
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        dbo.Trucks.Date_Out,    
        ISNULL(dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01].ProjectStart, N'1901-01-01') AS ProjectStart, 
        ISNULL(dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01].ProjectFinish, N'1901-01-01') AS ProjectFinish, 
        CASE 
           WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) <> YEAR(GetDate())
              THEN SET @StartDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        END,
        dbo.Partners.Partner_Name
    FROM              
        dbo.DYN_NAG02 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Trucks ON dbo.DYN_NAG02.TruckId = dbo.Trucks.Truck_Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01] ON dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01].TruckId = dbo.DYN_NAG02.TruckId 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Partners ON dbo.[DYN_NAG02].Partner_Id = dbo.Partners.Partner_Id
    WHERE           
        dbo.DYN_NAG02.DateExecution >= @StartDate
END
GO
```

Comment: Instead of `SET`, try `SELECT`

Comment: a case expression returns a value - its not a statement and cannot contain a statement. You can't use `set` inside a `select` just use `@StartDate = case ...`

Comment: And you cannot combine a select which returns values with a select which assigns values. So will need 2 selects one to assign and one to return values.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use table alias instead full table name.

Please check below updated stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Truck_Life] 
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Declare variables
    DECLARE @CurrentYearFirstDate DATETIME,
        @TodayDt DATETIME

    --Set variable values
    SET @TodayDt = GETDATE()

    SET @CurrentYearFirstDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @TodayDt), 0)

    --Update Store Procedure Parameter
    SELECT
        @StartDate = 
            CASE 
               WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) <> YEAR(@TodayDt) THEN @CurrentYearFirstDate
               ELSE @StartDate
            END

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        T.Date_Out,    
        ISNULL(DN1.ProjectStart, N'1901-01-01') AS ProjectStart, 
        ISNULL(DN1.ProjectFinish, N'1901-01-01') AS ProjectFinish, 
        @StartDate AS StartDate, --Use Store Procedure Parameter
        P.Partner_Name
    FROM dbo.DYN_NAG02 AS DN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Trucks AS T ON DN.TruckId = T.Truck_Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01] AS DN1 ON DN1.TruckId = DN.TruckId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Partners AS P ON DN.Partner_Id = P.Partner_Id
    WHERE DN.DateExecution >= @StartDate --Use Store Procedure Parameter in condition

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do your stored procedure. Since you are not using any columns in your condition, you can set the newStartDate before your query.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Truck_Life] 
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS    
BEGIN
    DECLARE @newStartDate datetime;
    SET newStartDate = @StartDate;

    IF (YEAR(@StartDate) <> YEAR(GetDate()))
        SET  @newStartDate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0);

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        dbo.Trucks.Date_Out,    
        ISNULL(dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01].ProjectStart, N'1901-01-01') AS ProjectStart, 
        ISNULL(dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01].ProjectFinish, N'1901-01-01') AS ProjectFinish
        dbo.Partners.Partner_Name
    FROM dbo.DYN_NAG02 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Trucks ON dbo.DYN_NAG02.TruckId = dbo.Trucks.Truck_Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01] ON dbo.[DYN_NAG04B-01].TruckId = dbo.DYN_NAG02.TruckId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Partners ON dbo.[DYN_NAG02].Partner_Id = dbo.Partners.Partner_Id
    WHERE dbo.DYN_NAG02.DateExecution >= @newStartDate;    
END
GO
```

Comment: The problem is I pass the value of @StartDate to a dashboard parameter. With your solution is still don't have the good value for it.